# Star Trek book with a battle (ongoing in the story) that is so large it looks like a sun

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, books

I am trying to find a Star Trek book where a battle is occurring. The battle is so big that it looks like the sun. The battle occurs at the end of the book

Comment: This is nowhere near enough information for anyone to figure it out for you. We'll need a lot more than one sentence. When did you read it, was the book new at the time, what era of *Star Trek* was it, any characters who were in the book, what the cover looked like, etc.. Anything you can remember can help.

Comment: Especially the era and characters.  Another thing would be the races involved and the names of any ships.

Answer (score 10):

The Voyager novel *[Ragnarok](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067152044X)* is about two races locked in combat - their weapons were underdeveloped compared to their shield technology, so the battle consisted of millions of ships pressing against one another until a ship's shields failed and it was crushed.

Voyager approached, **mistaking it for a strange star** based on the energy output, I believe.

After trying to determine the cause of the battle, of which both sides do not remember how it started, Voyager somehow gets involved (naturally) and finds a way to shift the frequency of their phasers to slice through the ships, destroying many on both sides of the conflict.

In the end, both sides agree to a cease fire to fight their new enemy, the Federation. The only problem is that their top speed was warp 1 or 2, so they won't be in Federation space for a thousand years.

Comment: “Voyager... finds a way to shift the frequency of their phasers to slice through the ships, destroying many on both sides of the conflict” — yikes! Doesn’t sound very Federation-y.

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: I believe it was Ragnarok.
https://www.amazon.com/Ragnarok-Star-Trek-Voyager-No/dp/067152044X

Comment: Yup sure sounds like the Voyager novel Ragnarok.  I have read it and own it.  The above answer is more or less a direct excerpt from that novel.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the novelization of *Star Trek: Insurrection*?

Chapter 13, page 279:

> *Picard closed his eyes, but for a blazing milli-second, it was like staring wide-eyed at a daytime sun...then the brightness dimmed....*

It's not really that big of a battle though; this was just a struggle between Picard and Ru'afo.